# What's the best way to add a tag to each log message using Nlog?

Tags: c#, nlog

I want to add specific tag to each log message inside different classes. Something like this:

```
class A
{
    private string tag = "Tag A";
    public DoSomething()
    {
        Logger.Debug("Some message",tag: tag);
    }
}
```

I found one solution:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
LogEventInfo eventInfo = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Trace,  
    "Hello from RunJob", logger.Name);
eventInfo.Properties["CustomerID"] = "someCustID";
eventInfo.Properties["TargetSite"] "someTargetSite";

logger.Log(eventInfo);
```

But perhaps there is some simpler way? At the moment I'm thinking of creating a wrapper.

Comment: what is the *purpose* of that tag? I don't know much about nlog, but I am pretty sure they don't have such things. Can't you just append the string at the end of your debug-message?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain for example mac address

Comment: and how should nlog display that? NLog has no idea about "tags", so you need a way to append that tag somewhere in your log-string, e.g. directly at the end. However we have no clue how your logged message should look like, so we can't give you any advise on that.

Comment: Of course Nlog has no idea, because of that I asked advice how to add a tag , prefix, context to each log message inside the class. Creating LogEventInfo quite inconvenient, every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pretty easy

```
logger.WithProperty("myProperty", "myValue").Info("Hello");
```

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context

Comment: How does this fit into the sample-messages in the question, e.g. `"Some Message"` and `"Tag A"`?.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain like this:

`logger.WithProperty("tag", tag).Debug("Some message");`

The result the same I have log message with tag.